# How to remove background controls from popup?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am developing web application in Angular 2. On button click I am trying to open popup. I am able to do it in JavaScript. I am trying now in Angular 2.

Below is my HTML code for popup inside main page.

```
 <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>

  </div>
```

In main page I have one text box. When I open popup inside popup text box is also displaying as below.
[image]

Filter records text box is in html page and not in popup. Can someone help me to fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've applied a high `z-index` to the filter records textbox and button; `z-index` is a styling attribute that allows you to specify which things appear in front of others, by lowering the `z-index` on your "Filter records" textbox/button they should sit behind the popup.

Read more on `z-index` here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp